# Converting string to double with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: swift, xcode6, nsnumberformatter

I am having trouble converting a string to a double in Swift.  This is my code:

```
var myDouble = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("41.363615")!.doubleValue
```

It is changing the value to

```
41.363615000000003
```

What is going on?

[image]

Comment: That's because of the way doubles are stored in memory. Consider using NSDecimal instead.

Comment: Latest xCode beta (playground) does display the value properly

Comment: Look at the IEEE754 encoding on Wikipedia or whatever. That's the way floating point numbers are encoded. You'll never be able to get _exact_ floating point numbers.

Comment: How would I convert a string to a double and keep the same percision? I am trying to use the CLLocation method from MapKit and I'm getting an invalid location error because of this.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `dataLatitude` is being set to `-93.xxxx` which is out of range for a latitude which must be from -90 to +90.  Perhaps your latitude and longitude values are backwards.  Notice your hard-coded values are the other (right) way around.

Comment: In Playground, the conversion seems to work fine. But not in my app :(

Comment: Thanks @Anna! My call to CLLocation works now!  I've been chasing this for a hour.  Seeing the double value changing precision while debugging was throwing me off.